# PHP partially interpreted on localhost

Tags: php, localhost

everything was nice few days ago, but today, on 1 of my local sites, PHP is partially interpreted.

My scripts :

index.php

```
<?php
##############################################################
## Définitions des chemins d'accès à / et au dossier admin  ##
## Initialisation de l'interface                            ##
##############################################################
DEFINE('ROOT_PATH', '');
DEFINE('ADMIN_PATH', ROOT_PATH . 'admin/');
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'init.php');

##############################################################
## Définitions des scripts/styles à charger pour la page    ##
##############################################################
$scripts_to_load = array();
$styles_to_load = array();

##############################################################
## Traitements PHP                                          ##
##############################################################
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'rate') {

    // on stocke les données postées en session
    $_SESSION['form-rating'] = $_POST;

    // on vérifie qu'aucun champ obligatoire n'est vide
    if(!empty($_POST['server']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['rating'])) {

        // on vérifie si le summoner existe dans la base de données
        $handler_summoners = new Handler_Summoners();
        $summoner = $handler_summoners->get_summoner_from_server_and_name($_POST['server'], $_POST['name']);

        // si le summoner n'existe pas encore, on le créé
        if(!$summoner) {
            $summoner = new Summoner();
            $summoner->server_id    = $_POST['server'];
            $summoner->name         = $_POST['name'];
            $summoner->create();
        }
```

and what is renders on Firefox, on localhost :

> get_summoner_from_server_and_name($_POST['server'], $_POST['name']); // si le summoner n'existe pas encore, on le crÃ©Ã© if(!$summoner) { $summoner = new Summoner(); $summoner->server_id = $_POST['server']; $summoner->name = $_POST['name']; $summoner->create(); } // on instancie le vote $rating = new Rating(); $rating->summoner_id = $summoner->id; $rating->rating = $_POST['rating']; $rating->comment = $_POST['comment']; $rating->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // on verifie que le vote est permis if($rating->is_permitted()) { // on enregistre le vote $rating->create(); // notice $notice = new Notice('success', 'Thank you! Your choice was successfully submitted.'); $notice->sessionize(); } else { // notice $notice = new Notice('danger', 'Sorry, but... You recently rated this summoner. Wait a bit longer before rating this summoner again.'); $notice->sessionize(); } } else { // notice $notice = new Notice('danger', 'Sorry, but... One or several fields are empty.'); $notice->sessionize(); } // redirection header('Location: index.php'); exit(); } ############################################################## ## Chargement du header ## ############################################################## require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'includes/inc.head.php'); ?>
>   _s($config->site_name); ?>

```
Home
About
Contact
```

It's like the beginning of my PHP script is not interpreted by server (I can see CSS and JS files are not loaded) and from line 29, PHP is output'd in the page.

On my remote server, everything works fine, page is perfectly rendered.

I'm using EasyPHP :
APACHE 2.4.2
MYSQL 5.5.27
PHP 5.4.6

Few days ago, i uninstalled a malicious browser plugin (installed itself on FF, Chrome and IE) which was injecting enhanced link tooltips (with some random websites screenshots) on random words on my web pages. Could this be related ?

Have any clue about what to do to solve my PHP problem ?

Comment: View the page source, I'd be willing to bet you see the rest of your PHP code :) It's that `<?php` looks like an opening tag to the browser, and you have the object operator `->` right before `get_summoner_from_server_and_name()`, which looks like the closing `>` for the open HTML tag. That's why it doesn't get rendered, but it's still there in the page source. **tl;dr;** None of your PHP code is getting interpreted.

Comment: and so, what should i do to solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your PHP is not being parsed locally any more. Are you sure you are requesting the script via a php enabled web server and not directly from the filesystem. (does your url start with file:// ?)

If that is not the problem you should look at what recent changes you made to your php.ini and httpd.conf (or IIS installation).

**edit:** as can be seen in the comments, it turned out to be a .htaccess

Comment: any specific directives in httpd.conf and php.ini I should look for ?

Comment: @VaN First start with telling us the url you see/are using in your browser. Are you going through the webserver? Second tell us if you indeed changed httpd.conf or did any updates to your httpd (apache). Ow and btw is the script file actually a .php file? You didnt rename it to .php.bak or .php1234 or .html or .test or anything but .php?

Comment: I'm browsing my file with localhost url, and apache running. I didn't change httpd.conf nor php.ini recently, and the file is a PHP file. Could a virus/maicious broswer plugin write in httpd.conf ?

Comment: It could but it seems a bit far fetched. You can try and look to see their last modification date. Do you have a backup of them? Can you also please pastebin the entire php file? Maybe there is something before what you already showed us. And are you calling this php directly or first another script. Do other scripts work? ... quite a lot of questions...

Comment: last modification date of httpd.conf and php.ini are 2012-12-08, which might be when I installed easyPHP. Here are pastebin from my files. index.php : http://pastebin.com/xGZugVUs , init.php : http://pastebin.com/ncYgAgsG , inc.head.php : http://pastebin.com/AN5NkA1b

Comment: I dont know if this could be related, but when I browse my others localhost websites, i get this error : Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed. It's like none of my localhost websites are running well anymore...

Comment: This is getting too weird ... Sure this situation has been working in the past :) ? ... OK, check to see if there is a .htaccess file in the  website directory.

Comment: ohh, found it. there was a .htaccess in the folder, with AddType x-mapp-php6 .php directive.. Dont even know what it was for. problem is solved  then. Thank you.